# Программно включить/отключить RPI_LCD

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Есть **Raspberry Pi Model 3 B** и экран к нему **Waveshare 3.5inch RPi LCD (B)**
Подключается через GPIO лапы. Экран подсвечивается, что крайне бесит особенно ночью. Можно его как-то отключить через SSH и включить при необходимости?

В интернете нашел несколько рецептов. Но не один из них не заработал

Пробовал так

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/fb_ili9325/bl_power
```

Но у меня папка **/sys/class/backlight** пустая

---

При попытке через **xset** отключить

```
xset dpms force off
```

Получаю

> xset:  unable to open display ""

---

На Raspbian нет **vbetool**, поэтому такой вариант тоже не получился

```
vbetool dpms off
```

---

Думаю можно как-то отрубить питание на GPIO, но я только начинающий железячник, и это вызывает у меня пока что сложности, к тому же со специфическим девайсом

Comment: Это зависит от того как в ядре и в железе реализована подсветка. Судя по названию драйвера это никакой не GPIO, а самый настоящий SPI, что означает необходимость посылки специальных команд *из драйвера*, либо, если же подстветка реализована сбоку через GPIO, управление этой линией. У меня есть подобный дисплей, но я смогу проверить это только дней через 10.

Comment: Был бы очень признателен. 10 дней ничто по сравнению с не найденным решением)

Comment: Да вы были правы. SPI. Как понимаю нужно на 19-й пин что-то послать)
http://www.waveshare.com/3.2inch-rpi-lcd-b.htm

Осталось выяснить что)

Comment: @0andriy, ping)

Comment: https://github.com/notro/rpi-firmware/issues/6